# How can I trigger the playlist carousel for a youtube video automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube, playlist

I'm guessing this isn't possible, as I can't find any documentation on doing this, but here's what I'd like:

Embed a Youtube playlist in a page. When users load the page, the player displays the other videos in the playlist as an overlay (just like when you click the playlist icon at the bottom of the screen). This way, it's completely apparent to the user that the video is part of a playlist, and they're encouraged to select other recent additions to the playlist instead of just playing the most recent.

I'm open to Javascript workarounds if that's what's necessary.

Comment: @moraleida I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this posting is old but I needed an answer as well and found this:
Google Product Forums > Youtube > Show Playlist By Default on an Embedded Player

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/lOcgw_PYPbg

Posting by i40WebStudiosLevel 1 
Hey I got it to work with &showinfo=1  !!!
example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?  list=UU4bTI6xqAGpQnfvg0w3TT9g&amp;hl=en_US&showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playlist

Comment: doesn't work anymore :-(